# Render formulas on same page

Tags: math-mode

Using this code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{mdwtab}
    \usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
    \newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
    \begin{document}

\begin{figure}  
$$
\sigma( w^T x + b) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(w^T x + b)}}
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Sigmoid function}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}  
$$
J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{(i)}\log(a^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-a^{(i)})
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Cost function}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
$$
J = \overline{J}
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Take mean of J}
\end{figure}

    \title{ \LaTeX\\
    }
    \author{\textbf{\Large }\\
        \textbf{\Large }
    }
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \np
    \tableofcontents
    \np
    \end{document}
```

renders third figure:

```
\begin{figure}
$$
J = \overline{J}
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Take mean of J}
\end{figure}
```

on second page of generated pdf document despite there being ample space available on current page for figure 3.

How can I amend my code so that all figures use max amount of space available on page?

Update :

Have tried using `\begin{equation}`   , `\end{equation}` as suggested in comments

:

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{mdwtab}
    \usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
    \newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
$$
\sigma( w^T x + b) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(w^T x + b)}}
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Sigmoid function}
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation} 
$$
J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{(i)}\log(a^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-a^{(i)})
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Cost function}
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation} 
$$
J = \overline{J}
$$
\vspace*{-7mm}
\caption{Take mean of J}
\end{equation} 

    \title{ \LaTeX\\
    }
    \author{\textbf{\Large }\\
        \textbf{\Large }
    }
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \np
    \tableofcontents
    \np
    \end{document}
```

but returns error :

[image]

Have also tried `\[ \]` but same error.

The $ symbol is defined within math expressions correctly ?

I'm using mactex (http://www.tug.org/mactex/) with TexShop (http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/)

Comment: To display a math expression, don't use `figure`. Use `\[ \]` or `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` (without `$` signs).

Comment: Just replace the three instances of `\begin{figure}` with `\begin{figure}[h!]`. And, please read the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Comment: Do you really want “Figure 1: Cost function” in order to describe the function?

Comment: @egreg no , the 'figure 1:' is auto generated. I'm learning how to write mathjax within tex.

Comment: @Sigur please see update

Comment: As Sigur told in the first comment, use `\[\]` or `equation` _without_ dollar signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really must use a `figure` environment, use just one, not three separate ones.

However, I suspect you'll be better off not using a floating environment, such as a `figure`, at all. Instead, consider loading the `amsmath` package and using a `gather*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "gather*" env. and "\tag*" macro
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\[
\sigma( w^T\!x + b) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(w^T\!x + b)}}
\]
\caption{Sigmoid function}

\bigskip
\[
J = -\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m}
\bigl[y^{(i)}\log(a^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-a^{(i)})\bigr]
\]
\caption{Cost function}

\bigskip
\[
J = \overline{J}
\]
\caption{Take mean of J}
\end{figure}

\hrule

\begin{gather*}
\sigma( w^T\!x + b) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(w^T\!x + b)}}
\tag*{Sigmoid function} \\
J = -\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m}
\bigl[y^{(i)}\log(a^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-a^{(i)})\bigr]
\tag*{Cost function} \\
J = \overline{J}
\tag*{Take mean of $J$}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: will use gather instead, can each caption be aligned to right of each formula ? Currently it's aligned right to page of each formula.

Comment: @blue-sky - Sure, just replace each instance of `\tag*` with `\quad\text`.

Comment: @blue-sky - By the way, did you notice I inserted a pair of square brackets in the middle formula?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, this appears to achieve expected result :

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{mdwtab}
    \usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
    \newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
\sigma( w^T x + b) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(w^T x + b)}}
\text Sigmoid
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation} 
J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{(i)}\log(a^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-a^{(i)})
\text Cost
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation} 
J = \overline{J}
\text Mean
\end{equation} 

    \title{ \LaTeX\\
    }
    \author{\textbf{\Large }\\
        \textbf{\Large }
    }
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \np
    \tableofcontents
    \np
    \end{document}
```